# ¿Cómo modificar el ancho de columnas en un JTable?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy buscando la forma de cambiar el ancho de las columnas de mi `Jtable`. Para el diseño utilizo una herramienta gráfica, pero no encuentro la opción correspondiente.

Answer (score 5):

Esta es la contruccion para hacerlo desde el codigo:   `JTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);`

Si usted tiene una tabla de x, usted tiene que definir todas pues JTable necesita tener los tamaños de todas para funcionar.

```
TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();

    columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
    columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
    columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(200);
    columnModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(250);
```

Comment: @JorgeGonzales no estoy seguro, pero no se si lo que usted quiere hacer es posible desde en editor, le dejo como hacerlo desde el codigo, quizas ayude. Saludos

Comment: lo busque en otros lados y no encontré nada al respecto, asi que seguramente tengas razón, usare el código.

Answer (score 4):

1. Tener un JTable :o)
2. Cambiar la propiedad "autoResizeMode" a OFF.
3. Click derecho en el JTable e ingresar a la opcion "Table Contents".
4. Ir a la pestaña "Columns"
5. Selecionar la columna a la que queremos fijar el ancho.
6. Cambiar el valor "Pref. Width" al ancho que queramos.